How can I get manim to not include some points when making a surface?
I'm fairly new to manim and I'm trying to graph the surface y^2 + z^2 = x^2 + x + 23 in manim. It should look like this.
I tried to do this by defining 2 functions and graphing them separately: f(x, y) = sqrt(x^2 + x + 23 - y^2) and g(x, y) = -1 * sqrt(x^2 + x + 23 - y^2). However, when I tried to graph this there were some values of x and y which returned negative square roots. So, as of right now I made it so when x^2 + x + 23 - y^2 is negative, I set the output to be 0. This makes a plane looking thing on the xy plane as seen here. Is there anyway to plot the proper surface without the plane thing?
Here is my code:
from manim import *

class ThreeD_ECC(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        axes = ThreeDAxes(
            x_range=[-10, 10, 1],
            y_range=[-10, 10, 1],
            z_range=[-10, 10, 1],
            x_length=20,
            y_length=20,
            z_length=20,
        )

        def func1(x, y):
            value = (x**3 + x + 23 - y**2)
            return np.sqrt(value) if value >= 0 else 0

        surface1 = Surface(
            lambda u, v: np.array([u, v, func1(u, v)]),
            u_range=[-2.726, 4],
            v_range=[-8, 8],
            fill_opacity=0.5,
            color=BLUE,
        )

        def func2(x, y):
            value = (x**3 + x + 23 - y**2)
            return -1 * np.sqrt(value) if value >= 0 else 0 

        surface2 = Surface(
            lambda u, v: np.array([u, v, func2(u, v)]),
            u_range=[-2.726, 4],
            v_range=[-8, 8],
            fill_opacity=0.5,
            color=BLUE,
        )

        self.add(axes)
        self.set_camera_orientation(phi=65 * DEGREES, theta=135 * DEGREES, gamma=0 * DEGREES, zoom=0.3)
        self.play(Create(surface1), Create(surface2))
        
        self.wait(5)

I tried returning None when x^2 + x + 23 - y^2 is negative. However, manim doesn't seem to allow arrays with None in them.
So I tried making it so when None is returned, change the entire array to the "vertex" of the surface ([-2.726, 0,  0]) which makes the surface look stretched as shown here
